# Ext JS - create a tool with dynamic tooltip on a panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, tooltip, panel

I have a panel and that panel has a load of tools.

these are defined in an array,
eg:

```
myPanel.tools = [
{
    type : 'down',
    tooltip : 'Down',
},
{
    type : 'up',
    tooltip : 'Up',
},
{
    type : 'help',
    tooltip : 'Blah Blah',
}
]
```

But the above is fine if the tooltip is static, but I would like it to be updated whenever the user mouses over it.

Can you pass a function to the config to call when moused over or right before its shown? Is there another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tooltip excepts an config object where you can add a listener:

```
tooltip: {
    listeners: {
        'render': function(comp){
             comp.tooltip = "enter your tooltip";
        }
    }
}
```

now you can modify the component like you want.

Comment: Yes it was that simple...
I think I was looking at it and doing to much so it never actually updated!
Just for clarity in your answer - inside the listener to set the tooltip add
comp.tooltip = "enter your tooltip";